# Flutter signing key changed: Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, code-signing, flutter-android

this problem was caused because I changed my Mac and having lost the key I had to generate a new one and then with Google assistance we made the new key official.
Previously all the process described here [Build and release an Android app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reference-the-keystore-from-the-app) worked fine.

The current situation is instead of through the command
`flutter build appbundle`
the build is signed with another key (I think the debug key) different from the current one as reported by the Play Console during the upload.

The properties in the `key.properties` file are correct, the path of the new key is correct. I had tried a while ago to clear the cache but nothing to do.

If, on the other hand, I go to open only the 'android' folder fot Flutter project with Android Studio, and I make the build through Build menu **the build is signed with the new key, the correct one**.

[image]